# Rails 3 loading static files, and the difference between development and production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Using Rails 3.2.2 and ruby 1.9.2, and finding issues when going from development to production.  If I just have a simple test page in public/ it seems to load in development mode, but in production mode, I get this:

The page you were looking for doesn't exist.

You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.

Then I go back to development mode, and it (!?!?) stops working there, too.  How can I print where it it trying to get static files from?  Also looking for a good explanation on all the differences between development and production in Rails 3, if you know of one. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting it in public/assets.  For production mode set config.serve_static_assets to true in config/environments/production.rb

Have a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html to learn about the asset pipeline in Rails 3.

Comment: This was the key for me:    RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile  I did it locally, then I took the newly created files in public/assets, and uploaded to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should watch two webcasts created by Ryan on assets pipeline. It was real frustration for me as well initially while working with asset pipeline and after watching both webcasts couple of times, I think I now have proper understanding of assets pipeline and now I love the whole asset pipeline concept.

Ur:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline

http://railscasts.com/episodes/341-asset-pipeline-in-production

Comment: Thank you! I will check those out.